# Jar FileNotFoundException caused by write to a xml File

Tags: java, xml, file, resources

I am trying to write to a XML file. It runs correctly in eclipse. The file is located at ca/ism/wen/domain folder (together with my user.java). However, it is throws `FileNotFoundException` when I run the exported runnable jar file. Is there way to write to an xml file in the jar file? Following is my code.

```
package ca.ism.wen.utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import ca.ism.wen.domain.User;

/**
 * Load XML file
 * 
 */

public class XmlFactory {

    private static Document dom;
    //private static File file = new File(User.class.getResource("UserRDP.xml").getPath());
    private static InputStream filei = User.class.getResourceAsStream("UserRDP.xml");
    private static File fileo = new File(User.class.getResource("UserRDP.xml").getPath());

    static {

        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = db.parse(filei);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Document getDom(){
        return dom;
    }

    public static void saveDom(){
        try {
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();            
            DOMSource ds = new DOMSource(dom);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(fileo);
            trans.transform(ds, sr);
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
}
```

If I have to put my XML file externally somewhere, I want to get a runnable file and put it in a folder under my whole project (just like normal software), cause it may be deployed to other person's machine later. Is that possible?

Comment: Where is your input file located?  You might try using the full path if it is not in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide an implementation for `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` as a third party library to your classpath as per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new File(User.class.getResource("UserRDP.xml").toURI());
```

The appropriate constructor of the `File` should be used to locate the resource. This approach only works with exploded jar. You cannot write to a jar, however you can read from it using jar protocol.

Comment: It gives me an error "Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException". Thanks.

Comment: Add exception handling to `try/catch` or add declaration to a method.If your file is in jar you should use somethig like `(JarURLConnection)inputURL.openConnection().getInputStream()`

Comment: Hi Roman C, thanks for your kind comments. I tried it in a try/catch. However, when I run the jar file, it still throws erros "Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0' java.lang.RuntimeException: URI is not hierarchical
 at ca.ism.wen.utils.XmlFactory.saveDom(XmlFactory.java:54)".

Comment: Don't create a jar, as I said it will not work with archived files. Why do you put xml files in jar when you need to write to it?